# IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4 & Scala compile server : IDE can't connect to its own local server

Tags: intellij-idea, scala-compiler

I'm using **IntelliJ IDEA 2017.3.4** as `Scala` IDE.

I have activate the "`Build project automatically`" option and set the `Java 8 JDK` as default project SDK.
[image]

Bellow, the `Scala compiler server` configuration
[image]

The `Scala compiler server` is **running** and listen on port **43558**. I can't change this port, I think this is affected randomly by IntelliJ IDEA.

[image]

When I make modification of my Scala source code, the IntelliJ IDEA don't use the `Scala Compiler Server` to avoid recompile many classes on a little change. Due to this reason, compilation time is so long...

I got the error bellow: 
[image]

```
Warning:scalac: Cannot connect to compile server at localhost/127.0.0.1:3200
Trying to compile without it
```

Note: I'm running on Linux Host 64 bits (Arch Linux)

Have you any idea about what I need to do for using `Scala compiler server`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, I need to hard code the port of the Scala Compile Server

Edit file **~/.IntelliJIdea2017.3/config/options/scala.xml** and add two options: `COMPILE_SERVER_PORT` and `COMPILE_SERVER_MAXIMUM_HEAP_SIZE`

Your file need to look like that content bellow:

```
<application>
  <component name="ScalaSettings">
    <option name="COMPILE_SERVER_PORT" value="43558" />
    <option name="COMPILE_SERVER_ID" value="xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx" />
    <option name="COMPILE_SERVER_SDK" value="1.8" />
    <option name="COMPILE_SERVER_MAXIMUM_HEAP_SIZE" value="2048" />
  </component>
```

Restart your IDE, you will be happy, It's working!